Stationarity vs. ergodicity of generalized Kesten process
Not an expert here. I am trying to figure out conditions that guarantee (i) existence of a stationary distribution, and (ii) ergodicity for the following generalized discrete-time Kesten process
\begin{equation}
x_{t+1}=\alpha_{t+1} \, h(x_t)\, +\, \beta_{t+1}, \quad t \geq 0, \quad x_0>0
\end{equation}
where $\left\{\alpha\right\}_t$ and $\left\{\beta\right\}_t$ are independent i.i.d. random sequences, each featuring a smooth probability density on closed real intervals $[0, \overline{\alpha}]$ and $[\underline \beta, \overline \beta]$, with $\underline \beta >0 $; moreover, $h(\cdot)$ is a continuous, non-decreasing real-valued function satisfying
\begin{equation}
h(x_t)
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll} 
>0 & \mbox{if and only if} \quad x_t > \bar{x}    \\\\
0  & \mbox{otherwise } \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $\bar{x}>0$.
I am able to show that, under suitable restrictions on $(\alpha, \beta)$ and the $h(\cdot)$ function, the above process is an irreducible and a-periodic Markov chain which also fulfills a geometric drift condition (Meyn and Tweedie, 2009, Ch. 10), so that the underlying process is geometrically ergodic (and thus there exists a unique stationary distribution to which the chain converges for any arbitrary $x_0$).
Suppose now I restrict $\beta$ so that $\bar{x}>\overline{\beta}$, which -- given the properties of $\alpha$ and $h(\cdot)$ -- in turn implies $Pr(x_{t+n} \leq \bar{x}\, | \, x_t)>0$ for all $x_t$ and some finite $n\geq 1$, and $Pr(x_{t+1} > \bar{x} \, | \, x_t )=0$ for all $x_t \leq \bar{x}$, i.e. the set $[\underline{\beta}, \bar{x}]$ is absorbing. I conjecture the limiting (and thus stationary) distribution still exists and is unique (the one induced by the random variable $\beta$), with full measure in $[\underline\beta, \bar{x}]$. But I am totally confused about whether the process can be said to be ergodic, since some of the states $x_t > \bar{x}$ are not positive recurrent -- once the chain enters the absorbing set, it nevers escape it. What am I missing?
